# Streaming voice between two endpoint

Tags: python, sockets, audio

everyone, i'm using a python code to Stream voice between to endpoints.
the code doesn't give me an error i just stuck at some point i don't now why

- what im trying to achieve is i want to speak from one endpoint and hear my voice at the other end point
- i don't want to use TCP i want to use UDP so i can avoid the latency 
  the receiver cod

```
import socket
import pyaudio
import select

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 4096

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.connect(("172.20.10.6", 5555))
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, output=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

#while True :
#print("Enter a UDP M\n")
#MESSAGE = input("")
#sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode('utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

try:
    while True:
        data = sock.recvfrom(CHUNK)
        stream.write(data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

print('Shutting down')
sock.close()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

the sender

```
import pyaudio
import socket
import select

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 4096

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 5555

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  socket.SOCK_DGRAM , socket.IPPROTO_UDP) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    for s in read_list[1:]:
        print (s)
        s.send(in_data)
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, stream_callback=callback)
# stream.start_stream()
read_list = [sock]
print ("recording...")

try:
    while True:
        print ("1")
        readable, writable, errored = select.select(read_list, [], [])
        print ("2")
        for s in readable:
            if s is sock:
                (clientsocket, address) = sock.accept()
                read_list.append(clientsocket)
                print ("Connection from", address)
            else:
                data = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                if not data:
                    read_list.remove(s)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


print ("finished recording")

serversocket.close()
# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

as you can see the code stuck at where i print the number 2 it doesn't print it

the below code is to a UDP connection that only Send a String

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "172.20.10.6"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
print ("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print ("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
print ("message:", MESSAGE)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

while True :
    print("Enter a UDP M\n")
    MESSAGE = input("")

    sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode('utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "172.20.10.6"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

 while True:
     data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
     print ("received message:", data)
```

Comment: From simple to complex: can you send a simple string?

Comment: yeah i  just added it up there you can see it.

Comment: Ok. Now could you modify your original example to send the string? Try to modify as little code as possible.

Comment: `read_list` might not be defined when needed. Is your callback function called at least once or twice?

Comment: Which data are you streaming? I can't see where an audio file etc. is opened. Have you seen this example on how the callback function works? https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#id4

Comment: i'm trying to record my voice at one endpoint and send it to hear it from the other endpoint

Comment: Look for the line `wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')` in the link I sent above. This is the data they are streaming in the callback function using `data = wf.readframes(frame_count)`

Comment: Have you seen this? https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2016-March/706179.html

Comment: `input_device_index` parameter in `Stream()` correct?